# How can I get Longitude and latitude of Address Enter in Input field in react native

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, map-directions

I am showing google map Between two coordinate one is origin and other is Destination I want to convert input value into Longitude and latitude. Currently I set static values but I need to get longitude and latitude of values that Inter in input text

```
const [coordinates] = useState([
    {
      latitude: 51.5115,
      longitude: 10.1160,
    },
    {
      latitude:     51.521515,
      longitude: -0.127636,
    },
  ]);
  return(
 <View>


<MapView
       
       style={styles.map}
         initialRegion={{
           latitude: coordinates[0].latitude,
           longitude: coordinates[0].longitude,
           latitudeDelta: 2.0922,
           longitudeDelta: 2.0421,
         }}>
         <MapViewDirections
           origin={coordinates[0]}
           destination={coordinates[1]}
           apikey={"Google Api key"} 
           strokeWidth={4}
           optimizeWaypoints={true}
           strokeColor="red"
         />
         <Marker coordinate={coordinates[0]} />
         <Marker coordinate={coordinates[1]} />
       </MapView>

       <TextInput placeholder = "Enter Orgin " />

<TextInput   placeholder = "Enter Destination"  />  

 </View>
  )
   
  };
```

Comment: User will manually type coordinate in text field?

Comment: its not easy How can convert it in coordinates?

Comment: I think is not something easier,  why not request the current user location coordinate using Geolocation API

Comment: I did user location code its give me error undefined is not an object (evaluating navigator geolocation get CurrentPosition)

Comment: Can we have a quick meeting here emmbyiringiro@gmail.com. I just try to  help you figure out

Comment: Sure I messaged you please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the location with  Expo as below code snippet.

```js
import * as Location from "expo-location";


export const hasLocationServiceEnable = async () =>
  await Location.hasServicesEnabledAsync();

const getUserLocation = async () => {


  let result = null;

  const isLocationAccessEnabled = await hasLocationServiceEnable();

  /** Discard request coordinates when user location disabled. This required to avoid
   * continuously request location in contrary to the user preference
   */



  if (!isLocationAccessEnabled) {

    return result;
  } else {

    // Request location access permission 
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

  

    if (status !== "granted") {
  
      return result;
    } else {
      try {
        let { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

       
        result = coords || null;
      } catch (error) {

        console.error(error)
       
      }

      return result;
    }
  }
};

export default getUserLocation;
```